# Code runs (copy and paste) when on one sheet but does nothing when run from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, worksheet

This should be an easy fix but I cannot find the problem.

I've got 2 sheets 'DispoData' and 'Dormant'.
I want to fix and copy the date from "A1" in 'DispoData' to "C8:E8" in "Dormant" sheet.

The code works absolutely fine if I've got the 'DispoData' sheet Active and run the code but if I'm on any other sheet and run it, cells "C8:E8" on the 'Dormant sheet' is empty.

```
Dim wbTemplate As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDispoData As Worksheet, wsDormant As Worksheet
Set wbTemplate = Workbooks("Makro Stock Management Bundle TEMPLATE.xlsm")
Set wsDispoData = wbTemplate.Worksheets("DispoData")
Set wsDormant = wbTemplate.Worksheets("Dormant Stock")


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Add date from Dispo to Dormant sheet, convert to date and delete other writing
    With wsDispoData.Range("A1")
        .FormulaR1C1 = Left(Range("A1"), 10)
        .Copy wsDormant.Range("C8:E8")
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wsDormant.Range("C8:E8").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
```

I want the code to run no matter what sheet is active.
There is a lot of code so I only activate the screen updating at the end again. I've run the code step by step, and everything works, except the paste part, does nothing if I'm not running the code with the 'DispoData' sheet active.

Comment: `Left(Range("A1"), 10)` - the `Range("A1")` is unqualified and implicitly refers to `A1` on the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Great thank you! I just put 'wsDispoData.' in front of the second Range("A1"). Thanks @BigBen

Answer (score 1):

Fixed version: with help form @BigBen.

```
With wsDispoData.Range("A1")
    .FormulaR1C1 = Left(wsDispoData.Range("A1"), 10)
    .Copy wsDormant.Range("C8:E8")
End With
```

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as correct -- so everyone will know your question is answered